# How to reset device (Mac) identity from Internet providers perspective?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm on a cruise and there's free WiFi as long as you pretend to download their app before using it (when you click through, they give you access for a period of time)

However, apparently they've been counting how many times i click download the app, cause now it's saying I can only download the app 10 times. I've tried using a different browser and incognito but it's giving the same message, so I'm assuming they're tracking my device.

Is there a way to reset my devices identity so they don't know how many times I have clicked?

I use a MacBook

(As a side question, would anyone know how to get past their website blocker? I can search the web freely after I connect, but certain websites that allow you to message (ie; Facebook, YouTube) are blocked. Very surprised this site isn't)

Comment: Have you tried using a VPN?  Have you tried a User-Agent Switcher add-on for your browser?  You need to isolate how they are determining you should be blocked in order to work around it. You haven't provided much for us to go on.  Maybe edit your question to provide details on the website/app etc., the cruise line in question,  Screenshots etc.

Comment: Maybe its stored in a cookie on your browser

Comment: Ask the Cruise desk. They should be able to get you going. I have done that.